# Define getter using defineProperty

Tags: javascript

In our application we compress our JavaScript classes using UglifyJS which doesn't support being able to compress syntax like `onBlur = (event) => {}` as it returns `Unexpected token: operator (=)`.

To solve this problem we have used the following function to define them:

```
function _defineProperty(obj, key, value) {
    if (key in obj) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
            value: value,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true
        });
    } else {
        obj[key] = value;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

And then we use it inside our constructor like so:

```
class OurClass {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
            _defineProperty(this, "onBlur", event => {
     
            });
    }
}
```

Which works great! however it doesn't work for defining getters:

```
static get values() {
    return { index: Number }
}
```

Like so:

```
_defineProperty(this, 'values', () => {
    return { index: Number };
});
```

The getter is never defined and isn't accessible in the rest of the class in the same way that we were able to define the other methods...

How can we define the getter using this same function with `defineProperty`?

Comment: Why are you not using Babel?

Comment: @connexo We're using Sprockets with Harmony (via UglifyJS) because it's what Jekyll Assets uses to compress the JavaScript.

Comment: UglifyJS by the looks of it clearly is not an option in 2020 any more. I've been writing ES6+ since 2016, hard to imagine being restricted to ES5 again.

Comment: @connexo Agreed it's not ideal. You can use ES6 just not that particular syntax if you want to compress your JavaScript. Jekyll Assets is really nice... but unfortunately some of the dependancies are not as up to date as we'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) accepts two different formats for its third argument:

- data descriptor, which you currently use
- accessor descriptor, which allows for defining a getter/setter

So, for instance, you could extend your own `_defineProperty` function with an optional argument to indicate that a getter/setter is intended:

```js
function _defineProperty(obj, key, value, accessor) {
    if (accessor == "getter") {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
            get: value,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        });
    } else if (key in obj) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
            value: value,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true
        });
    } else {
        obj[key] = value;
    }
    return obj;
}

// simple demo
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        _defineProperty(this, "num", () => 3, "getter");
    }
}

console.log(new MyClass().num);
```

If you want it as a static method, then define it on the class (i.e. on the constructor):

```js
function _defineProperty(obj, key, value, accessor) {
    if (accessor == "getter") {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
            get: value,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
        });
    } else if (key in obj) {
        Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
            value: value,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true
        });
    } else {
        obj[key] = value;
    }
    return obj;
}

// simple demo
class MyClass {}
_defineProperty(MyClass, "num", () => 3, "getter");

console.log(MyClass.num);
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Much appreciated. I'll give that a whirl.

Comment: Do I need to do anything extra to make it defined as static?

Comment: A static property in JavaScript is nothing more than a property on the constructor (i.e. on the "class"). See addition to answer.

Comment: Thanks. That's perfect!